# Nginx node setup to custom directory

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am using nginx first time so need help.

My app is running in **/root/project1/tools**  (this directory is having server.js)

How i can connect nginx to this directory. I searched lot and do not find direct ans. Think nginx will find my server.js by port number not by path. is that true?

I am using linux ubuntu 18

More over nginx is throwing error

> 2018/10/23 06:14:51 [alert] 3822#3822: *2025 socket() failed (24: Too
>   many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1,
>   server: nativeiconba$

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/nativeiconbase.com**

```
 upstream app_yourdomain {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        keepalive 8;
    }



# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name nativeiconbase.com www.nativeiconbase.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nativeiconbase.com.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://nativeiconbase/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }


  root /root/project1/src/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /root/project1/src/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                proxy_pass http://10.139.32.25:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

And my node app is running on port 8080. Any idea what can i do to setup nginx. any reference to resource will be helpful.

Comment: Change `proxy_pass http://nativeiconbase/;` to `proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain;`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan now the error is 502 **connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:**

Comment: are you sure node app is running?  by checking port 8080

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes my node app is running 8080 and unable private IP

Comment: using `netstat -anpl | grep 8080` to see port 8080 is listening on node app or not ?

Comment: you should start node app first,

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I have update question with **etc/nginx/sites-available/default** may be this can help you to find error

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan output of netstat is **tcp        0      0 10.***.**.**:8080       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4661/node /root/pro
**

Comment: node is separated on other server ? or in the same server with nginx ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan node is running on same server and this ip is private ip 10.*.*.*

Comment: move `defaul` file to another folder , then reload nginx again, (ex. to `/home` folder)

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan how to do that ?

Comment: ssh to the server then `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/` and  `mv default /home/`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan not able to reload as it throw error **nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.**

Comment: whtat is error log ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62

Comment: check line 62 in nginx.conf file , comment out that line then reload ngnix, and post that line  here

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan line number 62 is **include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;**

Comment: change that line to  `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.com;`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan now error log is **connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 115.**.**.**,**

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is setup a **Reverse Proxy Server in Nginx**

Start your NodeJS Server on whatever port

```
node server.js
```

If you are using any process management tool like `pm2` then

```
pm2 server.js
```

Now in nginx config what you have to do is proxying all request to local nodejs server so

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  keepalive 8;
}



# the nginx server instance
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name nativeiconbase.com www.nativeiconbase.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nativeiconbase.com.log;

  # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
  # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

I have just changed the line `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080` in your code

Comment: that give error ** connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, **